# Sitecore 9 - Add an Image to a Link in the Footer

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9

A client is using Sitecore 9 - we are not Sitecore developers.

We've been asked a simple thing: add social media links to the Footer of their Sitecore site.

Its proving more difficult than expected.

I've added the links on other pages by editing the HTML directly via the WYSWIG editor.

But the Footer appears more restricted, only accepting the addition of templates like 'Link'.

The 'Link' template has an option to add an external URL but doesn't have an option to add an image.

The CMS looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to add a link, with an image, via the CMS (without the need to write Sitecore code), so the page chnages from this:

[image: no links]

to this:

[image: links inserted]

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to write Sitecore code, maybe you should think about using frontend.

- Find the views that holds the footer (probably Foundation/Footer.cshtml) or something like that.
  -To easily find where it is, follow these steps

  - Go to a content page Presentation Details that has footer (probably any)
  - Go to Controls
  - Find the footer rendering in there
  - Click on it
  - Grab the Datasource's value
  - Go to the Datasource's path
  - There should be a field holding the value of the view.
- Add some css class on the div that holds those items, and do your frontend stuff in there...

It is not a scalable solution, so I would highly recommend updating the Footer rendering by adding new fields and adapting the model/view. So that way a content editor could easily add a new value for each socials.